# Database not showing in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

My client gave me access to his hosting account in order to create a new user for his Wordpress site since he forgot the credentials for the old one.

I got the FTP account and opened `wp-config.php` and normally i found the database name so i can access it through phpmyadmin.
Guess what!
The database is nowhere to be found even though the site is working normally!
This is the strangest thing that happened to me all these years working with Wordpress.

Did this happened to someone else so you guys can help me whats happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the user (and originating host) you've been given to access the MySQL server has permission to the database(s) in question... if your user doesn't then they'll just not be visible.

Edit:

It does still strike me as a permissions issue given that (if I've understood this correctly) the only new thing is you've created a new user and MySQL hides databases if you don't have permission.

Vijay is right that there might be something in `wp-config.php` so it's certainly worth downloading that and seeing if all other dbs are listed exact the one you're after but if you're able to manually run SQL commands try checking who has access to the db in question:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select user from mysql.db where db='my_missing_database_name';
Empty set (0.000 sec)
```

However if you are already logged in as the `root` user then run the following to ensure all the permissions on this user are correct for all originating locations:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root';
```

Comment: Yes, i can see all the other databases except this one. I can also see the db user. Here's the databases. (the ...dp4 is missing): https://prnt.sc/rOLvTe6sdnfh And here's the db users: https://prnt.sc/SOr-ezu0DR3D (user called ...dp4 same as the db name is there).

Comment: I logged in to their Hostgator account and accessed phpmyadmin from there. There's no other account associated with that.

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting include/require another php file in `wp-config.php` and that another file holds all the constants, You can check if there is any file included in your `wp-config.php`